# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader... findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, andengine, game-physics

this error when running my project :

```
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): Process: com.brekol, PID: 1391
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.brekol-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.brekol-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.brekol.scene.GameScene.createPhysics(GameScene.java:119)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.brekol.scene.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:74)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.brekol.scene.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:30)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.brekol.scene.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:44)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.brekol.manager.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:75)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:94)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:618)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:605)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:57)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
05-28 07:52:04.314: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

PLEASE HELP ME!!! WHY THIS ERROR??

Comment: Thanks Golu !! my english is poor

Answer (score 1):

You missed import on native libraries, check https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples for details ;)

Comment: Thank you peter.But I've import all the required libraries.

Comment: @peter_budo could you please elaborate a bit? I don't understand the problem and AndEngineExamples has no details on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your project is not linking the .so files.

Its very simple. Follow this simple steps

**1)** Create a new folder called **"lib"** inside the libs folder of the **main app**.

**2)** Copy all the folders ie.armabi , armabi-v7a etc from **andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/libs** folder, and paste in in the previously created **"lib"** folder in **main app**.

**3)** Now compress the **"lib"** folder as **"lib.zip"** and rename it to **"lib.jar"**.
this changes the **zip** extension to **jar**.

**4)** Finally add a line -- **compile files('lib.jar')** under dependencies{} in **Build.gradle** file of your **main app**.

**5)** Clean and build the project.

my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068202/2026280